# Usar variables ciclicas en Random Forest machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning

He transformado una variable predictora de mi modelo de machine learning en una variable ciclica mediante senos y cosenos. Por lo que entiendo al aplica el Random Forest las variables predictoras son escogidas aleatoriamente para construir cada uno de los árboles. Al suceder esto es muy probable que no haya árboles dentro del modelo que tengan solo el cosenos y otras solo el seno. Esto podría resultar un problema?

Pasaría lo mismo si he codificado variables categóricas en dummievariables?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

> En efecto, las variables del modelo serán aleatorias y no siempre
> darán buenos resultados.

Por lo general funcionan muy bien cuando tomas datos por ejemplo de sensores donde el tiempo es una variable importante de tu target. Las opciones mas fáciles son como mencionas el seno y coseno de la hora por ejemplo. Puedes probar elegir de forma aleatoria variables de árboles simples  y ver su desempeño cuando se elije entre el conjunto de variables los senos y cosenos. Puedes graficar los árboles y ver la ganancia al utilizar el sin y cos en cada árbol.

> Otra opción es usar algún módulo para rankear las variables como
> featureimportance utilizando algún algoritmo de gradient boosting
> como: **xgboost o lightgbm.**